# Typescript debugging - show types

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript, typescript1.4

When debugging Typescript in VS2013, TS 1.4 in a Node.JS console project, the locals window and any added Watches show variables as either a value type or an Object - how can I get it to display the objects as classes or interfaces?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, as what you are debugging is JavaScript and not Typescript (which is not supported by the browser)

Answer (score -2):

> how can I get it to display the objects as classes or interfaces

Can't do it in the watch or local windows. However you can hover over the variables to see the types in the editor.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this that does not involve visual studio code by chance?